# All the data gets lost while converting pdf to PNG

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to convert PDF to PNG images to use it later in my application. I'm using pdfjs-dist library and NodeCanvasFactory functionality but all the data gets lost after the conversion from PDF to PNG.

```
class NodeCanvasFactory {
  create(w, h) {
    if (!w || !h) {
      throw new Error('invalid canvas size');
    }
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(w, h);
    return {
      canvas,
      context: canvas.getContext('2d'),
    };
  }
}
static async toPNG(document, pageNum)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      document.getPage(pageNum).then((page) => {
        const viewport = page.getViewport({
          scale: 1.0,
        });
        const factory = new NodeCanvasFactory();
        const data = factory.create(viewport.width, viewport.height);
        page.render({
          canvasFactory: factory,
          canvasContext: data.context,
          viewport,
        }).promise.then(() => resolve({
          page: pageNum,
          width: viewport.width,
          height: viewport.height,
          buffer: data.canvas.toBuffer(),
        })).catch(e => reject(e));
      }).catch(e => reject(e));
    });
  }
```

As Input i have this PDF File
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZkBE.png

As Output I get this PNG image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ozDS.png

How I can resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to conversion process not preserving the colors and data of the original PDF file. This can happen because the conversion process simplifies the content to an image representation which may cause some loss of fidelity.

To resolve this issue, you can try `pdf2pic` library that provides better control over the conversion process. By using `pdf2pic` you will have more control over the conversion settings such as DPI, output format, resolution, and quality. This should help preserve the colors and data of the original PDF file better.

```
const { PDF2Pic } = require('pdf2pic');

async function convertPDFtoPNG(inputPath, pageNum) {
  const pdf2pic = new PDF2Pic({
    density: 300, // Set the DPI (dots per inch)
    format: 'png', // Choose the output format (png/jpeg)
    size: '1024x768', // Set the resolution
    quality: 100, // Set the output image quality
  });
  
  const output = await pdf2pic.convertPDFtoImage(inputPath, pageNum);
  
  return {
    page: pageNum,
    width: output.width,
    height: output.height,
    buffer: output.base64,
  };
}

convertPDFtoPNG('input.pdf', 1).then(result => {
  console.log('Page converted:', result);
}).catch(error => {
  console.error('Conversion error:', error);
});
```